# Discord Bot. Trying to get the username of a user without message info

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

With the below code i'm trying to change the user role and then get the username so that it can be sent in a message to the specific channel. However, it keeps returning Undefined for the username in the produced message.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    // Set the member's roles to a new single role
    const GuildObj = guildMember.guild
    if (GuildObj.name = "GuildName") {
        guildMember.setRoles(['387154651365113866']).catch(console.error);
        client.guilds.get('308190520994430976').channels.get("593021188838522900").send("Welcome to the server " + guildMember.username + " you have successfully been given the role of lvl 1.")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `username` isn't a property of GuildMember but rather [`nickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname)

```
client.channels.get("593021188838522900").send("... " + guildMember.nickname + "...")
```

Comment: So `.nickname`returns null, but after looking at the GuildMember docs it turns out that `.displayName` works not `.nickname`.

Comment: Right! Nickname only output if they have one ;)